# REST User Registration API, How to handle validation

Tags: forms, 8

I am new to D8, Building an application with Drupal 8 REST and REST UI contrib module. Since 8.3 User Registration API is available. But if validation fails, it throws below error :

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

While I checked, recent report from Admin -> report section. It says : `Unprocessable Entity: validation failed. mail: The email address abc@example.com is already taken.` which is as validation in API fails.

But, How do I send a 400 (Bad request) with respective error message in response?

Any configuration or need to set something through a custom module?

Comment: I dont know, I always write my own routes and controllers.